# How do I replace all instances of lowercase k with a unicode character using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, replace

How do I replace all instances of lowercase k with a unicode character? I've got a webfont loaded, and the default k is pretty ugly, so I want to swap it for an alternate character (unicode 006b)

Been trying something along these lines but it doesn't work yet:

`$(this).html($(this).text().replace(/k/g,"\006b"));`

Comment: k and \006b are literally the same thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost there, add an `u` for `Unicode` (in JS)

```
$(this).html($(this).text().replace(/k/g,"\u006b"));
```

**Example:** *Replace `k` with Unicode "k" `006b`* hexadecimal

```js
var $el = $("#test")
$el.html($el.text().replace(/k/g,"\u006b"));
```

```html
<div id="test">kelly klarkson</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

**Still does not works?** That's because of `font-family` settings - which means that even if you replace the `k` with the Unicode value - the same stylized character might appear since it's settled in the same Unicode space-value. A remedy would be to replace it with a different `font-family` like:

```js
var $el = $("#test")
$el.html($el.text().replace(/(k)/g,"<span class='arial'>$1</span>"));
```

```css
#test {
 font: 16px/1.4  "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

.arial { /* JS-fix ugly "k" */
  font: 22px/1.4 Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">kelly klarkson</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

If you're a designer, I would always first suggest you open that silly font in a Font editor, edit the desired character and save as [*otf*, *ttf*](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5618/whats-the-difference-between-opentype-vs-truetype) and load the new font version by appending a query `?v=2` to your font URL in order to make sure the edited font is pulled by the browser.

---

Tip/Reminder for Unicode hexadecimals

- HTML: `&#x<hex>;`
- JS: `"\u<hex>"`
- CSS: `"\<hex>"`

Comment: Yeah, I ended up just editing the font and replacing the glyph, then regenerating the webfont. Turned out miles easier. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a cleaner approach would be to use only CSS.
The [`unicode-range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40font-face/unicode-range) property allows you to define on which character a font will be used:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'l';
  src: local('Comic Sans MS');
  unicode-range: U+006C; /* target only the letter 'l' */
}

div {
  font-size: 4em;
  font-family: l, cursive; 
}
```

```html
<div>Hello World</div>
```